# Are there are any side effects of using this method to convert a string to an integer

Tags: javascript, numbers, parsefloat

Are there any side effects if i convert a string to a number like below..

```
var numb=str*1;
```

If I check with the below code it says this is a number..

```
var str="123";
str=str*1;
if(!isNaN(str))
{
  alert('Hello');   
}
```

Please let me know if there are any concerns in using this method..

Comment: to be safe you would parseInt(str)*1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you use `parseFloat`, or `parseInt`, the conversion is less strict. `1b5` -> 1.

Using `1*number` or `+number` to convert will result in `NaN` when the input is not valid number. Though unlike `parseInt`, floating point numbers will be parsed correctly.

### Table covering all possible relevant options.

```
//Variables    // parseInt  parseFloat  + 1* /1   ~~ |0 ^1 >>0  >>>0
var a = '123,',//   123        123       NaN       0     & <<0   0
    b = '1.e3',//   1          1000      1000      1000          1000
    c = '1.21',//   1          1.21      1.21      1             1
    d = '0020',//   16         20        20        20            20
    e = '0x10',//   16         0         16        16            16
    f = '3e9', //   3          3000000000  <--    -1294967296    3000000000
    g = '3e10',//   3          30000000000 <--    -64771072      4230196224
    h = 3e25  ,//   3          3e+25     3e+25     0             0
    i = '3e25',//   3          3e+25     3e+25     0             0
    j = 'a123',//   NaN        NaN       NaN       0             0
    k = '  1 ',//   1          1         1         1             1
    l = '    ',//   NaN        NaN       0         0             0
    m = '.1  ',//   NaN        0.1       0.1       1             1
    n = '1.  ',//   1          1         1         1             1
    o = '1e999',//  1          Infinity  Infinity  0             0
    p = '1e-999',// 1          0         0         0             0
    q = false ,//   NaN        NaN       0         0             0
    r = void 0,//   NaN        NaN       NaN       0             0
    _ = function(){return 1;}, /* Function _ used below */
    s={valueOf:_},//NaN        NaN       1         1             1
    t={toString:_};// 1        1         1         1             1

// Intervals: (-1e+20, +1e20)  (-∞,+∞)   (-∞,+∞)   (-2³¹,+2³¹)   [0, 2³²)
// In FF9 and Chrome 17, Infinity === Math.pow(2, 1024), approx. 1.7976e+308
// In FF9 and Chrome 17, bitwise operators always return 0 after about ±1e+25
```

### Notes on number conversion methods:

- The number conversion always fail if the first character, after trimming white-space, is not a number.
- [**`parseInt`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) returns an integer representation of the first argument. When the radix (second argument) is omitted, the radix depends on the given input.
  `0_` = octal (base-8), `0x_` = hexadecimal (base-16). Default: base-10.
  *`parseInt` ignores any non-digit characters, even if the argument was actually a number: See **h, i**.*
  To avoid unexpected results, always specify the radix, usually 10: `parseInt(number, 10)`.
- [**`parseFloat`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) is the most tolerant converter. It always interpret input as base-10, regardless of the prefix (unlike `parseInt`). For the exact parsing rules, see [here](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1).


  *The following methods will always fail to return a meaningful value if the string contains any non-number characters.* (valid examples: `1.e+0 .1e-1`)
- `+n, 1*n, n*1, n/1` and `Number(n)` are equivalent.
- `~~n, 0|n, n|0, n^1, 1^n, n&n, n<<0` and `n>>0` are equivalent. These are [signed bitwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers) operations, and will always return a numeric value (zero instead of `NaN`).
- `n>>>0` is also a [bitwise operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.3E.3E.3E_%28Zero-fill_right_shift%29), but does not reserve a sign bit. Consequently, only positive numbers can be represented, and the upper bound is 2<sup>32</sup> instead of 2<sup>31</sup>.
- When passed an object, `parseFloat` and `parseInt` will only look at the [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method. The other methods first look for [`.valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/ValueOf), then `.toString()`. *See **q - t**.*
- **`NaN`**, "Not A Number":
  `typeof NaN === 'number'`
  `NaN !== NaN`. Because of this awkwardness, use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check whether a value is `NaN`.

### When to use which method?

- `parseFloat( x )` when you want to get as much numeric results as possible (for a given string).
- `parseFloat( (x+'').replace(/^[^0-9.-]+/,'') )` when you want even more numeric results.
- `parseInt( x, 10 )` if you want to get integers.
- `+x, 1*x ..` if you're only concerned about getting true numeric values of a object, rejecting any invalid numbers (as `NaN`).
- `~~, 0| ..` if you want to always get a numeric result (zero for invalid).
- `>>>0` if negative numbers do not exists.
  *The last two methods have a limited range. Have a look at the footer of the table.*

The shortest way to test whether a given parameter is a *real number* is explained at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525899/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-number-is-a-real-valid-number/8526029#8526029)**:

```
function isNumber(n) {
    return typeof n == 'number' && !isNaN(n - n);
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer.. Thanks alot for taking time :-)

Comment: NP. If you read the answer carefully, you can compose additional number checking methods, eg: `function isNumber(n){return +n === n && n - n === 0;}`