# How to check if a JavaScript number is a real, valid number?

Tags: javascript, numbers, int

MY code is:

```
function isNumber(n){
return typeof n == 'number' && !isNaN(n);
}

window.onload=function(){
var a=0,b=1,c=2.2,d=-3,e=-4.4,f=10/3;
var shouldBeTrue=[a,b,c,d,e,f];

var aa="0",bb="1",cc="2.2",dd="-3",ee="-4.4",ff="10/3";
var shouldBeFalse=[aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff];

var aaa,bbb=true,ccc=false,ddd=document.getElementsByTagName('html');
var alsoTheseBeFalse=[aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,""," ",,null,NaN];

for(var i=0;i<shouldBeTrue.length;i++)
    if(isNumber(shouldBeTrue[i]) != true) alert("x");
for(i=0;i<shouldBeFalse.length;i++)
    if(isNumber(shouldBeFalse[i]) != false) alert("x");
for(i=0;i<alsoTheseBeFalse.length;i++)
    if(isNumber(alsoTheseBeFalse[i]) != false) alert("x");
}
```

What else should I check against to ensure my function is 101% perfect in all ways? (also, if you know a better function please tell me)

Comment: which function are you looking to make perfect? You could start by giving your variables more meaningful names...

Comment: @frenchie: He's talking about the `isNumber(n)` function.

Comment: There were numeric cases you didn't check, but I cant make your function break (ie: g=2E30, gg=0/0)

Comment: @Brian, well 0/0=NaN (and I did check for that), but I am curious about the '2E30' thing because it returns true. Do you know why it returns true?

Comment: Side note, inside your test cases, you're using `!= false`. This is not needed, because your `isNumber` function always return a boolean (`true` or `false`). Within `if ( ... )`, an expressions is always treathed as a boolean. `if (isNumber(a) != false)` is equivalent to `if (isNumber(a) == true)` is equivalent to `if (isNumber(a))`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to check whether a number is a real number, you should also check whether it's finite:

```
function isNumber(n){
    return typeof n == 'number' && !isNaN(n) && isFinite(n);
 }
```

Another method (explanation below):

```
function isNumber(n){
    return typeof n == 'number' && !isNaN(n - n);
}
```

### Update: Two expressions to validate a real number

Since JavaScript numbers are representing real numbers, the substraction operand on the same number should produce the zero value [(additive identity)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_identity). Numbers out of range should (and will) be invalid, `NaN`.

```
1        - 1        = 0    // OK
Infinity - Infinity = NaN  // Expected
NaN      - NaN      = NaN  // Expected
NaN      - Infinity = NaN
```

Comment: Well, your code is larger and do 1 more operation. The only way I would use it is if you to tell me a way that my current function would fail and yours not

Comment: @TuxedoKnightChess Input the following value: `Infinity`. It passes the first two tests, while it's not a useful real number: `isNumber(Infinity)` returns true for your current function.

Comment: what would be the result for `var n=2E30;`?

Comment: @TuxedoKnightChess: There's a real easy way to find out.

Comment: @TuxedoKnightChess I've updated the answer with another method. Two tests instead of one.

Comment: Just to double check, both of your functions do exactly the same thing?

Comment: @TuxedoKnightChess The methods slightly differ, but the results are exactely equal.

Comment: Real numbers are finite per definition.

Comment: how come this function is not embedded in Javascript, is for me a big huge surprise. Dealing with true numbers (integers or float) is a basic task of any programming language

Comment: btw, can I give 10 of my points to you. I feel like +1 is just not enough

Comment: your `isNumber(n)` function is *perfect* . No variable coercion and all that typical mess of javascript, no `string`, no `"1"`, no `true`, no `"true"`, no `NaN`, no `null`, no `1/0`. `n` must simply be a finite valid number (integer or float). And `0` returns true as it should be.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev what the OP meant is not real in the mathematical sense, but merely a true number (natural, integer, rational or real numbers, in the mathematical sense). Javascript is a mess dealing with types and type coercion and believe me that this function is very, very important.

Answer (score 2):

JS numbers can be among the following values:

- Finite numbers
- `+Infinity` and `-Infinity`
- `NaN`

Then there also non-number values which are coercible to numbers, e.g. number objects. You might want to consider them numerical.

If you only want to test finite numbers, simply use [`Number.isFinite`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.isfinite):

```
Number.isFinite(value)
```

```js
var isNumber = Number.isFinite;
assert('isNumber(1)', true);
assert('isNumber(1.1)', true);
assert('isNumber(+0)', true);
assert('isNumber(-0)', true);
assert('isNumber(-1.1)', true);
assert('isNumber(Math.PI)', true);
assert('isNumber(1e300)', true);
assert('isNumber(+Infinity)', false);
assert('isNumber(-Infinity)', false);
assert('isNumber(NaN)', false);
assert('isNumber(null)', false);
assert('isNumber(undefined)', false);
assert('isNumber(true)', false);
assert('isNumber(false)', false);
assert('isNumber("123")', false);
assert('isNumber("foo")', false);
assert('isNumber(new Number(1))', false);
assert('isNumber([])', false);
assert('isNumber({})', false);
assert('isNumber(function(){})', false);
function assert(code, expected) {
  var result = eval(code);
  console.log('Test ' + (result===expected ? 'pass' : 'FAIL') + ': ', code, ' -> ', result);
}
```

If you want to include infinities, check the type and exclude `NaN`:

```
typeof value === "number" && !Number.isNaN(value)
```

```js
function isNumber(value) {
  return typeof value === "number" && !Number.isNaN(value);
}
assert('isNumber(1)', true);
assert('isNumber(1.1)', true);
assert('isNumber(+0)', true);
assert('isNumber(-0)', true);
assert('isNumber(-1.1)', true);
assert('isNumber(Math.PI)', true);
assert('isNumber(1e300)', true);
assert('isNumber(+Infinity)', true);
assert('isNumber(-Infinity)', true);
assert('isNumber(NaN)', false);
assert('isNumber(null)', false);
assert('isNumber(undefined)', false);
assert('isNumber(true)', false);
assert('isNumber(false)', false);
assert('isNumber("123")', false);
assert('isNumber("foo")', false);
assert('isNumber(new Number(1))', false);
assert('isNumber([])', false);
assert('isNumber({})', false);
assert('isNumber(function(){})', false);
function assert(code, expected) {
  var result = eval(code);
  console.log('Test ' + (result===expected ? 'pass' : 'FAIL') + ': ', code, ' -> ', result);
}
```

If you want to consider number objects as numbers, you can unwrap them using

```
value = Number.valueOf.call(value); // throws if value was not a number object
```

```js
function isNumber(value) {
  try { value = Number.prototype.valueOf.call(value); } catch(err) { }
  return Number.isFinite(value);
}
assert('isNumber(1)', true);
assert('isNumber(1.1)', true);
assert('isNumber(+0)', true);
assert('isNumber(-0)', true);
assert('isNumber(-1.1)', true);
assert('isNumber(Math.PI)', true);
assert('isNumber(1e300)', true);
assert('isNumber(+Infinity)', false);
assert('isNumber(-Infinity)', false);
assert('isNumber(NaN)', false);
assert('isNumber(null)', false);
assert('isNumber(undefined)', false);
assert('isNumber(true)', false);
assert('isNumber(false)', false);
assert('isNumber("123")', false);
assert('isNumber("foo")', false);
assert('isNumber(new Number(1))', true);
assert('isNumber([])', false);
assert('isNumber({})', false);
assert('isNumber(function(){})', false);
function assert(code, expected) {
  var result = eval(code);
  console.log('Test ' + (result===expected ? 'pass' : 'FAIL') + ': ', code, ' -> ', result);
}
```

If you want to include arbitrary values coercible to numbers, you can use the unary `+` to coerce.

```
value = +value; // throws if value was not number-coercible
```

There is also the [`isNaN`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-isnan-number) function (not to be confused with `Number.isNaN`), which will first coerce and then compare with `NaN`. But be aware whitespace strings and `null` are coerced to `+0`, not `NaN`. So you might be interested in [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18082/1529630)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you wish to regard as a number. Your code classifies Infinity and -Infinity as numbers. If you don’t want that, replace !isNaN(n) by isFinite(n).

And your code classifies '42' (a string literal) as not being a number, due to the type check; but I supposed that’s intentional.

Answer (score 0):

I use combination of parse and check for numbers.. as outlined below

`function isNumber(inputValue){
return ((parseFloat(inputValue) ==0 || parseFloat(inputValue)) && !isNaN(inputValue)); 
};`

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For react or other framework users, possible solution could be:

```
const { onChange, value } = this.props;
return (
  <input
    type="text" // Note: I have kept this as text
    value={typeof value !== 'number' || isNaN(value) ? '' : value}
    className={classnames('input')}
    onChange={(event) =>
      onChange &&
      onChange(parseFloat(event.target.value))
    }
  />)
```

This works on safari as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you consider a number in its object wrapper to be a number, then it will fail with:

```
isNumber( new Number(123) )
```

---

Since a downvoter is having some comprehension troubles that couldn't be alleviated by a simple test, `new Number(123)` will return `'object'` from the `typeof` test, and as such will not pass.

Comment: @down-voter: Give a reason. Please tell me how `new Number(123)` will pass the `isNumber` test in the question.

Comment: I did not downvote, but your code only shows an example of something that breaks the code, without proposing a solution. The OP did not ask how to break the function, but how to *improve* the function.