# How can I implment isRationalNumber?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I looked at this answer and was not satisfied:

[How to check if a JavaScript number is a real, valid number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525899/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-number-is-a-real-valid-number)

I thought it would be faster and more concise to do:

```
Pub.isRealNum = function (check) {
    return ( check === +check ) && (check !== Infinity) && (check !== -Infinity);
};
```

Are there any cases I'm missing?

It works for

```
1 ( true )
1.1 ( true )
0 ( true )
Infinity ( false )
NaN ( false )
"foo" ( false )
function(){} ( false )
```

Does underscore have an equivalent?

I looked briefly here at the API but did not see any thing:

http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: Does this work when you input strings or other objects?

Comment: I'd like to mention that your usage of _real_ is a bit confusing - I thought you wanted to detect numbers that are only real, not just to see if it's a number.

Comment: @vlaz I thought the same, but you would just be passing in NaN if you tried to give it an imaginary number like Math.sqrt(-1).

Comment: @Samy - yes it does.

Comment: @Jecoms I was thinking more along the lines of separating reals from integers and/or rational numbers or something.

Comment: @vlaz Real numbers include both rational and irrational numbers.

Comment: Use the built in methods `isNaN` and `isFinite`. Your requirements for a "real" number value are not defined so this question is too vague to answer correctly.

Comment: A computer can not represent an irrational number.  I think I should have called the method `isRationalNumber`

Comment: @Jecoms and integers. But that's not the point, I can very well see a use for figuring if a number is only in the real set, but not in any of the others.

Comment: @C Aaker but you would want Math.PI to return true, right?

Comment: @Jecoms - It is a rational number as it an estimate of PI, not actual PI.

Comment: @C Aaker You're right. I suppose I've never tried to work with irrational numbers in code before.

Comment: I have updated the question to say ... isRational, but perhaps it should be isFinite and discarded as it is part of the API now.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`Number.isFinite`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.isfinite).

> 1. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*number*) is not Number, return **false**.
> 2. If *number* is **NaN**, **+∞**, or **−∞**, return **false**.
> 3. Otherwise, return **true**.

```js
assert('Number.isFinite(1)', true);
assert('Number.isFinite(1.1)', true);
assert('Number.isFinite(+0)', true);
assert('Number.isFinite(-0)', true);
assert('Number.isFinite(-1.1)', true);
assert('Number.isFinite(+Infinity)', false);
assert('Number.isFinite(-Infinity)', false);
assert('Number.isFinite(NaN)', false);
assert('Number.isFinite(null)', false);
assert('Number.isFinite(undefined)', false);
assert('Number.isFinite(true)', false);
assert('Number.isFinite(false)', false);
assert('Number.isFinite("123")', false);
assert('Number.isFinite("foo")', false);
assert('Number.isFinite(new Number(1))', false);
assert('Number.isFinite([])', false);
assert('Number.isFinite({})', false);
assert('Number.isFinite(function(){})', false);
function assert(code, expected) {
  var result = eval(code);
  console.log('Test ' + (result===expected ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL') + ': ', code, ' -> ', result);
}
```

Comment: or, `Number.isSafeInteger` if you're interested in `int` only.

Comment: This seems like the best solution, but semantically, I think it can be vague since irrational numbers are not really "finite" but they are Real numbers.

Comment: Wow, what was the purpose of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525899/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-number-is-a-real-valid-number

Comment: @CAaker it was posted in 2011 and I don't think `Number.isFinite` was around then

Comment: @Jecoms Irrationals are finite numbers. Because they are not infinity. Their decimal representation is not finite, but that's a different thing. You can even express certain irrationals in a finite representation in certain basis.

Comment: @Oriol by this function's definition, sure.

Comment: @Jecoms No, I mean they are finite in math.

Comment: @CAaker Here is a finite representation of `π` using base `π`: `10`. It does not go on forever.

Comment: Going on forever has nothing to do with being infinite. E.g. 1/3 "goes on forever" when written decimal, but is neither irrational nor infinite. This debate is off topic.

Comment: The representation of PI in decimal goes on forever and never approaches a single value.

Comment: @CAaker `π` approaches `π`, just like `2` approaches `2`. Numbers are abstract things, their properties do not depend on their representations.

Comment: This is ES6, where can I get an overview of browser that support this.

Comment: @CAaker Use `typeof value === "number" && isFinite(value)`. Will work even with ES1.