# VueJS sum up all number values in data row

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In my data array I have rows per person filled with a couple of number values like this:

```
  {
    name: 'John doe',
    monday: 29837,
    tuesday: 30753,
    wednesday: 28079,
    thursday: 27144,
    friday: 27016,
  },
```

I need to calculate the total value per week. The only way I manage to get this is by displaying em like:
`{{ props.row.monday + props.row.tuesday }}` But I'm sure there is a way better way than this.

Comment: You can [loop through properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8312459/4636715) of your object; and maybe can sum up [checking their types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525899/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-number-is-a-real-valid-number) or if the keys end with `-day`. It depends on your exact possible structure and approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum the values of a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449295/how-to-sum-the-values-of-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this (in JS ES6):

```
Object.values(yourObject).filter(item => typeof item === 'number').reduce((a,b) => a+b)
```

Explanation:

- `Object.values()` selects all the values of your object
- `.filter()` filters your values so only numbers remain
- `.reduce()` loops through the array and adds all the members together

A good article on the ES6 stuff: 
https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d

Object.values explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Comment: This fixes what was going to be my next issue (total amount of every person). I need this per person aswell. Anyway i can filter that out?