# convert money format into numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following tag in html i do not want the $ to be taken as i just want the price for calculations purpose.

```
<span id="testspan">$101.82</span>
```

in the above span tag i want to take only 101.82 value for calculations .

I am using the html() to get the value

```
var csqft_price = $('#testspan').html();
var price= parseFloat(csqft_price);
```

but i am getting it with $ so i am unable to do calculation how can i do it.

Comment: Can you influence how the HTML you show is generated?

Comment: Note: this isn't really a jQuery question - you might want to retag as JavaScript.

Answer (score 19):

You can use

```
var csqft_price = $('#testspan').html();
var number = Number(csqft_price.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
```

**This was already posted on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559112/how-to-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-double-with-jquery-or-javascript).**

Answer (score 3):

The following tests whether the first character is a dollar-sign and if so takes the rest of the string:

```
var csqft_price = $('#testspan').html();
var price = +(csqft_price.charAt(0)==="$" ? csqft_price.substr(1) : csqft_price);
```

Of course, if you know that there will *always* be a dollar-sign you can just do this:

```
var price = +csqft_price.substr(1);
```

Note: I generally prefer the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29) to convert a string to a number, so I've used that in my answer above - you can change `+(...)` to `parseFloat(...)` if you prefer.

Comment: The sample number in the question didn't go into the thousands, but if you might have a number with the format `$12,000.01` (i.e., with commas) then I'd recommend using a `.replace()` like in Hemant's answer (it removes all characters except digits and full-stops).

Comment: Casting to a number using `parseFloat` is more permissive than `+`. See also: [Are there are any side effects of using this method to convert a string to an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112757/are-there-are-any-side-effects-of-using-this-method-to-convert-a-string-to-an-in/8112802#8112802)

Comment: @Rob W - Sure, but the only difference is it ignores non-numeric trailing characters isn't it? I would use `parseFloat()` only when I explicitly wanted that effect.

Comment: @nnnnnn In this case, it shouldn't matter, since the format is predefined. I just mentioned the difference as a FYI ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would replace all non digets and dots with nothing and make than a parseFloat:

```
var textValue = '$101.82';
var floatedValue = parseFloat(textValue.replace(/[^\d\.]/, ''));
alert(floatedValue);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MEY9R/

Comment: Please note, this fails if there is a comma in the number as is common in Canada/US (among other countries) EG: 1,101.82, http://jsfiddle.net/nathankoop/MEY9R/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
var csqft_price = $('#testspan').html();
var price=parseFloat(csqft_price.replace('$',''));
alert(price);
```

And use price for calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the $ sign by using the javascript "replace" function and replace the $ sign with an empty value, like this:

```
var vsqft_price = $('#testspan').html();
var vsqft_float = vsqft_price.replace("$", "");
var price= parseFloat(csqft_float);
```

Comment: Not flexible enough. Just work for dollars and does not respect any other possible chars (like spaces)

Comment: @Armin - this answers the question as asked, where the format seems to be known (and doesn't have spaces).

Comment: Yes, but the other solution (via regexp) fits your requirements too and is a much more flexible way to solve it! Other users who read this, should know about this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
   var csqft_price = $('#testspan').text();
    var s = csqft_price.substr(1);
    alert(s);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Answer (score 0):

ku4js-kernel has a sweet $.money class for this. You can just $.money.parse("$101.82") and then do what you want.

You could get the value() and use as a number or even better, just keep as money and do your operations. You can check out the documentation [here](http://kodmunki.github.io/ku4js-kernel/#money).