# String slicing in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
export class Prices{
value : string;
}

const PRICES : Prices[] =[
{value :'$10,000'},{value :'$20,000'},{value :'$30,000'},{value                 
:'$40,000'},{value :'$50,000'},
{value :'$60,000'},{value :'$70,000'},{value :'$80,000'},{value 
:'$90,000'},{value :'$100,000'},
{value :'$125,000'},{value :'$150,000'},{value :'$175,000'},{value 
:'$200,000'},{value :'$225,000'},
{value :'$250,000'},{value :'$275,000'},{value :'$300,000'},{value 
:'$325,000'},{value :'$350,000'},
{value :'$375,000'},{value :'$400,000'},{value :'$425,000'},{value 
:'$450,000'},{value :'$475,000'},
{value :'$500,000'},{value :'$525,000'},{value :'$550,000'},{value 
:'$575,000'},{value :'$600,000'}]


export class ConstantProperty implements OnInit{
prices=PRICES;
selectedPriceMin : Prices;
}
```

I am selecting the price from a drop down menu in html,
Now I want to slice that selected price in order to remove dollar sign.

Comment: What have you tried to remove the dollar sign?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert money format into numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654456/convert-money-format-into-numbers)

Comment: The answer to this question is available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), but this is probably not the right question. What you should be asking is, "What is the best way to parse currency in a locale independent way?"

Answer (score 0):

To remove a dollar sign (or any character) from the front of a string, do

```
var withoutDollarSign = withDollarSign.substr(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example:  `"$550,000".replace("$","");`

That results in "550,000"

Answer (score 0):

Slicing a string is easy as:

```
"$400.00".slice(1);
```

or

```
var currencyString = "$400.00";
var valueString = mystring.slice(1);
```

Where the 1 is the index the character you want to slice at.

This assumes that the $ sign will always be at the 1st position.

Answer (score 0):

If `{value :'$10,000'}` is the structure of your data, then, 
you could remove the `$` sign in this way:

```js
const data = [{value :'$10,000'},{value :'$20,000'},{value :'$30,000'},{value:'$40,000'},{value :'$50,000'},
{value :'$60,000'},{value :'$70,000'},{value :'$80,000'},{value 
:'$90,000'},{value :'$100,000'},
{value :'$125,000'},{value :'$150,000'},{value :'$175,000'},{value 
:'$200,000'},{value :'$225,000'},
{value :'$250,000'},{value :'$275,000'},{value :'$300,000'},{value 
:'$325,000'},{value :'$350,000'},
{value :'$375,000'},{value :'$400,000'},{value :'$425,000'},{value 
:'$450,000'},{value :'$475,000'},
{value :'$500,000'},{value :'$525,000'},{value :'$550,000'},{value 
:'$575,000'},{value :'$600,000'}];


console.log(
  data.map(i => Object.assign({}, i, {value: i.value.substr(1)}))
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to apply [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on each item.

```js
console.log(
[{value :'$10,000', region: 'NY'},{value :'$600,000', region: 'NY'}]
    .map(({value,...rest}) => ({value: value.replace('$', ''), ...rest}))
);
```

Comment: this loses all the other `x` possible properties.

Comment: @Hitmands updated to hadle that case, but this code can be harder for OP to understand as it introduces more concepts.

Comment: you are using `Object spread operator` which is not standard, basically my same answer... And don't assume the OP as junior, because it is not needed in this context.

Comment: @Hitmands The code is in `Typescript`, I keep using object spread operator in Typescript as it appears less verbose to me. Again, its more of preferences and environment.

Comment: no, it is not. Object Spread Operator is under ecmascript proposal, this isn't standard and may be never released. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread

Comment: @Hitmands I do agree with your concern that it is stage3, but I hope it is fine to use it with TypeScript or Babel. Check an example and disclaimer [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html). If you can convince redux team and react native team, I'll consider too. Also it is safer to assume `Object spread` may confuse OP when OP is asking for a simple string operation, the original intention being not to dilute the answer by assuming requirements. `assign` and `substring` not the same as `spread` and `replace`.IMHO a similar answer is not offensive in SO.