# Javascript get number from string?

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing strings with prices and sometimes surrounded by characters.

How do I transform it from?

```
[0] > '$9.99/aa'
[1] > '$2.99'
[2] > '$1.'
```

to:

```
[0] > '9.99'
[1] > '2.99'
[2] > '1'
```

So I can do comparisons with the values? I just need to know how to change one and I can apply it to the array easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+myString.replace(/[^\d.ex-]+/gi, '')
```

strips out all characters that cannot appear in a JavaScript number, and then applies the `+` operator to it to convert it to a number.  If you don't have numbers in hex format or exponential format then you can do without the `ex`.

EDIT:

To handle locales, and handle numbers in a more tailored way, I would do the following

```
// Get rid of myriad separators and normalize the fraction separator.
if ((0.5).toLocaleString().indexOf(',') >= 0) {
  myString = myString.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
} else {
  myString = myString.replace(/,/g, '');
}

var numericValue = +(myString.match(
    // Matches JavaScript number literals excluding octal.
    /[+-]?(?:(?:(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?|0x[0-9a-f]+)/i)
    // Will produce NaN if there's no match.
    || NaN);
```

Comment: Your regex is quite... broad.

Comment: +1 the only thing I would add is I don't think this conversion (or any of the float conversions in js) are locale dependent. just an FYI

Comment: thanks, I still have a problem though. If the string is: "$1.99." I get "1.99.". Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: @Hello71, Liso22, you can narrow the regular expression by just looking for the number grammar.  I edited it to find valid numbers and to expect locale sensitive fraction separators.

Comment: @32bitkid, I edited it to use `0.5.toLocaleString()` to normalize fraction separators and myriad separators before converting to a number.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: I don't think that works. You may need to use `(0.5).toLocaleString()`.

Comment: Huh. Apparently not (in Firefox, anyways).

Comment: @Hello71, it's not required.  `0.toLocaleString` won't work because it is tokenized as `0.` followed by `toLocaleString`, but `0.5.toLocaleString` is tokenized as `0.5` then `.` then `toLocaleString`.  Edited since it's potentially confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Your case requires a Regular Expression, because all native number-converting methods fail when the string is prefixed by a non-digit/dot.

```
var string = '$1.22'; //Example
string = string.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, '');
// string = '1.22'
```

If you want to convert this string to a digit, afterwards, you can use `parseInt`, `+`, `1*`.

For a comparison of these number-converting methods, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112757/are-there-are-any-side-effects-of-using-this-method-to-convert-a-string-to-an-in/8112802#8112802)

Answer (score 1):

parseFloat() works for such cases when you need the decimals.  The regex will give the matched number for all your cases in the 0 index.  Sample code is below.

```
var one = "2.99";
var two = '$1.';
var three = '$3tees';
var four = '$44.10'    

var regex = /\d+\.?(\d+)?/;
var num = parseFloat(one.match(regex)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Strip everything before the first digit and apply `parseFloat` to the rest:

```
s = "$9.99/aa"
alert(parseFloat(s.replace(/^\D*/, '')))
```

Answer (score 0):

The lazy way:

```
+string;
```

The proper way:

```
parseInt(string, 10);
```

Thus:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var match = /\$(\d*)\.(\d\d)/.exec(arr[i]);
    arr[i] = parseInt(match[1] + match[2]);
}
```

Edit: Oh, you wanted something more than 10 dollars.

Another edit: Apparently `parseInt` (at least in my browser) ignores trailing characters. In that case, my original implementation would have worked.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = parseInt(arr[i].substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Read the question more closely.

Comment: neither of these work with the data provided. you just read the *title*, didn't you.

Comment: @RobW: Are you referring to the loop part or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
+/[\d\.]+/.exec('$9.99/aa')[0]
```

Finds the first group of digits and periods, converting them to a float