# Mozilla Firefox extension developing. 577 < 100. How is this possible?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

Here's something I haven't been able to figure out for the last 30 minutes.

```js
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].
                      createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath( sPath );
...
if ( file.fileSize < (offsetContent+bytesToRead) )
{
    wt.BO.log(file.fileSize + "<" + offsetContent + "+" + bytesToRead);
    bytesToRead = file.fileSize - offsetContent;
}
```

What the above code displays is: "577 < 50 + 50"... o.O How the hell is 577 < 100? The if statement is true...can't seem to figure why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plus operator (`+`) is used to concatenate strings, or to add up numbers in JavaScript.

Since `offsetContent` or `bytesToRead` are strings, both variables are concatenated:

- `"50" + "50" = "5050"`
- When comparing these values, the string is converted to a number, and
  `"5050" == 5050`       ->      `577 < 5050`   is true, of course.

Some methods to fix the code:

```
// Substract bytesToRead from both sides
if ( file.fileSize - bytesToRead < offsetContent )
// Or, Turn the comparison operator, and make the right side negative
if ( file.fileSize >= -bytesToRead - offsetContent )
```

Comment: `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` would do it to

Comment: haha..yes you are right ... can't believe i didn't think about that. I was getting the values from a XML message so...yeah... thanks again. This might go on 9gag. haha

Comment: and even one more method: file.fileSize < (1*offsetContent+1*bytesToRead) :)

Comment: @AndreiBogdan There are several ways to convert numbers. They're **not** equal though, see [this comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112757/are-there-are-any-side-effects-of-using-this-method-to-convert-a-string-to-an-in/8112802#8112802).