# Get element at point in entire page (even if it's not visible)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page and on it are some widgets.  There are 2 columns.  Widgets will auto-resize themselves if there is no widget to their left (or right).

I'm using [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:document.elementFromPoint) (after getting the widget's offset) to detect if there is a widget next to it.

There is a problem with `document.elementFromPoint` though.

> If the specified point is outside the visible bounds of the document... the result is *null*.

It only works if the element is in the viewport.  How can I detect what element is at a certain position even if it's not visible?

**EDIT**: Here's an example:

[image: Crappy Mockup]

The red line is the viewport, and the grey box (with the red writing) is Widget D's *original position* (the other Widget D is where it is when the page is done loading).  When the page loads, it checks Widgets B, C, and D.  It gets their offsets, and then uses `document.elementFromPoint` to see if Widget A is to their right.  If Widget A is to their right, the Widget is half width, if not it's full width.

Widget D is full width because `document.elementFromPoint` returns null because it's outside the viewport.  How can I detect that Widget A is to the right of Widget D even though it's outside the viewport?

Comment: If your code is not often executed, you can move the `html` or `body` element to the left/right/top/bottom, so that the element is temporary within the viewport. Another option: If you know which elements have to be compared, use `$('selector').offset()` (`.top` and `.left`), plus `.height()`/`.outerHeight()` and `.width()`/`.outerWidth()` to calculate the relative position of the elements.

Comment: @RobW: I tried to explain my issue with a crappy mockup.

Comment: So, you know which elements have to be resized relative to each other?

Comment: @RobW: Basically.  This page is customizable.  When it loads, each widget checks whether it should be half width or full width based on what is to its right.

Comment: By saying "each widget", you imply that there's a fixed number of elements which have to be checked. You can loop through each element, and combine the methods from my first comment to check whether there's an element right/left of the current element.

Comment: @RobW: That's my problem.  I can't figure out how to check whether there's an element to right/left if it's outside the viewport (`document.elementFromPoint` returns `null`).  Think you could whip up a quick answer to elaborate a bit on your suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code saves the boundaries of the elements in two lists: x and y positions. Then, you can use a `for-loop` to start at a given offset, and walk through the list. At the bottom of the answer, an implementation is shown.

```
// These arrays are going to contain many empty elements ;)
var xAxis = [];
var yAxis = [];

// Our storage. Each element looks like: [$element, top, right, bottom, left]
// Beware of cross-references! Deleted elements cannot be GCed if they're here!
var allElements = [];

/*
 * @param   $elem jQuery object
 * @returns Object containing the jQuery object and the floored border offsets
 */
function getBorders($elem) {
    $elem = $elem instanceof jQuery ? $elem.first() : $($elem);
    var offset = $elem.offset();           // Properties: top, left

    var width = $elem.outerWidth();        // Includes padding, border.
    var leftBorder = offset.left;          // Position of the left border ->|
    var rightBorder = leftBorder + width;  // Position of the right border  |<-

    var height = $elem.outerHeight();      // Includes padding, border
    var topBorder = offset.top;            // Position of the top border    _v_
    var bottomBorder = offset.top + height;// Position of the bottom border  ^

    // Turn all numbers in integers, so that they can be used as indexes
    //   for arrays
    // See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8112802/938089
    return {
        $elem: $elem,
        top: ~~topBorder,
        right: ~~rightBorder,
        bottom: ~~bottomBorder,
        left: ~~leftBorder
    };
}

$('.widget').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    var info = getBorders($this);
    allElements.push(info);
    // The positions are floored, so that they can be used as a quick reference
    xAxis[info.left] = xAxis[info.right] = info;
    yAxis[info.top] = yAxis[info.bottom] = info;
});
```

The created list can now be used to check whether there's any element which collides. For example, consider the following function:

```
function doesItCollide($elem) {
    // WeakMaps are useful. For compatibility, I don't use them.
    var info$elem = getBorders($elem);
    // info$elem properties: $elem, top, right, bottom, left
    // Y-oriented
    for (var y=info$elem.top; y<yAxis.length; y++) {
        var candidate = yAxis[y];
        // Not undefined, and not iself
        if (candidate && candidate.$elem[0] !== info$elem.$elem[0]) {
            // Check whether the element is inside the range
            if (candidate.top >= info$elem.bottom &&
                candidate.bottom >= info$elem.bottom) continue;
            // It's here, so the top / bottom are possibly in the same range
            // Check whether the x-positions are also colliding
            if (candidate.left >= info$elem.left && /* Left within range? */
                candidate.left <= info$elem.right || /* OR */
                candidate.right <= info$elem.right && /* Right within range? */
                candidate.right >= info$elem.left) {
                return candidate;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Example (**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LtJsM/**):

```
$('.widget').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var overlapping = doesItCollide($this);
    if (overlapping) {
        alert('Current element:  '+this.className +
           '\nColliding element: ' + overlapping.$elem[0].className);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm gonna need to tweak it a bit, but an array of element positions is a great idea :-)