# Does this === not work b/c of floating point rounding inaccuracies?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Let's say I have this snippet.

```
var age = prompt('what is your age?');

if (age === 30)
{
alert('your age is 30');
}
```

When I entered 30 in the prompt, the if statement doesn't trigger. I suspect it has to do with floating point rounding errors, but don't really know for sure. Would be great to hear your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`window.prompt()` returns a string. A string is not identical to a number. Use either of the following:

```
if (age === '30') 
if (+age === 30)  // Explicit type conversion
if (age == 30)    // Implicit type conversion
```

For notes on the explicit conversion, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8112802/938089?are-there-are-any-side-effects-of-using-this-method-to-convert-a-string-to-an-i). For example, An input of `00030` may also be valid.

Comment: OP might also be missing understanding of what === really means - might want to include that as well

Comment: @JRaymond If that's the case, I refer to this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Comment: I think the main issue is I got confused with string and number types. Perhaps I should convert the type in the prompt.