# How to increment a value at localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have some values that are dynamically stored at localStorage with incremented values like this: localStorage["Value0"], localStorage["Value1"],....

When I try to access them like this:

JavaScript:

```
localStorage["Counter"]=0;
var i = localStorage["Counter"]; 
var d =localStorage["Value"+i];
i = i + 1; // i becomes "01"
var f = localStorage["Value"+i];
```

The i's value is "01" not 1 ...  Is there a way to increment the i's value correctly?

Comment: please show your actual code, because your example is probably 'wrong' in the sense that when you set `i=0` and then increment it with `i=i+1` there is no way that you end up with the string `'01'`

Comment: Now, this is the actual code.

Comment: Because it's been stored as string, you have to parse it. `parseInt(localStorage['value0'])`;

Answer (score 17, accepted):

LocalStorage can only store string values. You can use parseInt which converts a string into an integer:

```
var new_value =  parseInt(localStorage.getItem('num')) + 1
```

You can also use libraries like store.js to do things automatically for you. All you have to do is to include the library:

```
<script src="store.js"></script>
```

Set a new storage:

```
var numbers = new Store("numbers")
```

Put things into it:

```
numbers.set('num', 2)
```

Get the value and do anything you want with it:

```
numbers.get('num') + 1 //output: 3
```

And you can also go crazy and use some arrays:

```
numbers.set('nums', [1,2,3])
```

And change things inside it:

```
numbers.get('nums')[0] + 3 //output: 4
```

No type conversion needed. You can also store objects, booleans and other stuff. Just don't forget to save things back in the storage since it doesn't automatically do it.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the problem of getting `01`, simply convert the variable to a number:

```
var i = +localStorage.getItem('Counter'); // or +localStorage.Counter;
```

If you want an incremental key name, the following code can also be used (provided that you don't delete keys in between):

```
var keyname = 'Value' + localStorage.length;
localstorage.setItem(keyname, value);
```

Comment: You can convert a string to a number with `parseInt()`

Comment: you can also do `i = i | 0;` to convert to integer

Comment: @padde `1*`, `+`, `~~`, and [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8112802/938089?are-there-are-any-side-effects-of-using-this-method-to-convert-a-string-to-an-in), depending on the conditions.

Comment: I have a lot of values stored at localStorage, what is the length that's supposed to be returned ?

Comment: @SanaJoseph The number of keys. For example, when you've got an empty storage, and use `localStorage.setItem('x','y');`, then `localStorage.length === 1`.

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` always returns string values. So to iterate them, I think it's better to use the conversion method. Here you can increment the key value in localStorage.

```
let k = 0;
k = k.toString();
localStorage.setItem(k, "ahmad");
k = parseInt(k);
k++;
k = k.toString();
localStorage.setItem(k, "bilal");
```

You can call the `localStorage.getItem()` method like this:

```
k = 0;
k = k.toString();
console.log(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(k)));
k = parseInt(k);
k++;
k = k.toString();
console.log(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(k)));
```