# How to increase value stored in session storage

Tags: javascript

I need to set value of a variable in session storage as 0.

Then check the value of the session storage whether it is less than a constant. If so assign a value to a variable and increment the value in session storage by 1.

How can I do this, please help me with a simple example.

Comment: What's your precise problem in there ? What did you try ?

Comment: what is section storage ?

Comment: I need to increase value of a variable till i close the tab, and need to use the value of that variable to predict value of another variable, i read it is possible with session storage

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should always show that you have a basic understanding of what you are asking, and show the code you have tried to solve your problem.

Passing that, using javascript Web Storage is pretty simple:

```
var constante = 1;
sessionStorage.setItem("variable",0);

var variable = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("variable"),10);
if(variable < constante ){
    sessionStorage.setItem("variable",variable + 1);
}
```

This is a very basic example of how you can do it, you should read the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Thanks, i think above example solve my issue. will check, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1)set default value of variable to 0 in sessionStorage

```
function setDefault(){    
  if(sessionStorage['chill'] === undefined) {
     sessionStorage['chill'] = x;
  }
}
setDefault();
```

2)write a function to get the variable ("here variable name is chill")

```
function getChill() {
   return parseInt(sessionStorage["chill"]);
}
```

3)now write a function to increment variable chill

```
function incrementChill(){
  var currentValue = getChill();
  if(currentValue > CONSTANT_VALUE){
     sessionStorage['chill'] = currentValue + 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is not so trivial as some said. The key here is that sessionStorage, same as localStorage only stores strings, as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375433/how-to-increment-a-value-at-localstorage).

Try this code:

```js
function f_Counter() {
  var ls_Contador_num = sessionStorage.getItem('ls_Contador_num');
  if (!ls_Contador_num) {
    ls_Contador_num = 0;
    sessionStorage.setItem('ls_Contador_num', ls_Contador_num);
  } else {
    ls_Contador_num = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('ls_Contador_num', ls_Contador_num)) + 1;
    sessionStorage.setItem('ls_Contador_num', ls_Contador_num);
  }
  console.log(ls_Contador_num);
}
```