# Setting a localStorage string to an Integer

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to make a save function for my game and, it isn't allowing me to save any of my Variables as integers (even with parseInt(Variable), +Variable, etc.)

The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375433/how-to-increment-a-value-at-localstorage) post aren't working.

```
    localStorage.value = value;
    value = localStorage.value;
```

Comment: Did you try HTMLxp = parseInt(localStorage.HTMLxp, 10);

Comment: @Oli Yes, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Just a pointer, you should put relevant code only. If you code is too big, try creating a small poc of it and share it.

Comment: @qwerty77asdf Are you trying to achieve something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb3s11u0/)

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, in a way if you view the website listed in the question you will see the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `parseInt(localstorage.numericProperty)`

```js
function populateStorage() {
  let obj = {x: "sdfsd", y: "sdfsdf"};
  
  localStorage.setItem("image", JSON.stringify(obj));

  localStorage.bgcolor = "blue";
  
  localStorage.numeric = 3;
}

function checkStorage(){
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("image"));
  console.log(localStorage.bgcolor);
  console.log(parseInt(localStorage.numeric) + 1);
}

populateStorage();
checkStorage()
```

Comment: look my example with objects

Comment: try to run your code in codepen, since I tested that and it is working fine.

Comment: when you load from local storage you need to use parseint(localstorage.value)
as in the example that I did in the learn css http://codepen.io/tiagofabre/pen/BKbyGq

    `
    learnSpeed = parseInt(localStorage.learnSpeed);
    `

Comment: look the example in code pen. add larncss save, load and try to learn more css...

Comment: I think you are not parsing every variables and it is causing a sum between an integer and a string...

Comment: Since in the codepen is working it could be something from your environment (os, browser or something like that)

Comment: did you see this working in the codepen ? I put an example there and worked for me...
http://codepen.io/tiagofabre/pen/BKbyGq
test if is working:
Click in leanrCSS -> Save -> Load and learnCSS again

Answer (score 2):

The best way to convert any number data in `localStorage` from string to number:

```
var a = localStorage['some_property'];

typeof a; // "string"

var b = +localStorage['some_property'];

typeof b; // "number"
```

Comment: plz give some example. What are you trying to store in localStorage? `localStorage['some_property'] = '123'` ?

Comment: Are you sure that everything ok at your side? Try this sample: https://jsfiddle.net/0ocp84kx/

Answer (score 1):

u can an object for storing in local storage as follows

```
  Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
    var value = this.getItem(key);
    return value && JSON.parse(value);
};


    localStorage.setObject('x', {1: 2, 2: "s"})
    console.log(localStorage.getObject('x'));
```

Comment: That includes JSON & jQuery, any other ways?

Comment: This is: `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: @AliMamedov is that not jQuery?

Comment: :) ... okay remove $.

Comment: @qwerty77asdf, Yes, you are completely right. It is jQuery!

Comment: use like this Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
    var value = this.getItem(key);
    return value && JSON.parse(value);
};


    localStorage.setObject('x', {1: 2, 2: "s"})
    console.log(localStorage.getObject('x'));

Comment: @92sharmasaurabh modifying built-in objects is not a good idea... `Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {...}`

Comment: Some words about Augmenting built-in objects. **Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition:** Augmenting built-in objects through the prototype is a powerful technique, and you can use it to shape JavaScript in any way you like. Because of its power, though, you should always thoroughly consider your options before using this approach. The reason is that once you know JavaScript, you're expecting it to work the same way, no matter which third-party library or widget you're using. **Modifying core objects could confuse the users and maintainers of your code and create unexpected errors**