# How to find the sum of variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var pagenumber = localStorage["pageno"];
var sum = pagenumber + i;
display(sum);
```

In this case i am getting the output sum = 11 (when input pagenumber = 1 and i = 1) , But i require the output sum = 2

Comment: You need to parse your string to a number.

Comment: `var pagenumber = +localStorage["pageno"];`

Comment: `localStorage["pageno"]` returns an string `'1'`

Comment: Both values _(or the first)_ aren't numbers but strings. `1 + 1 = 2` and `'1' + '1' = '11'`. Use `parseInt(localStorage["pageno"])` to parse it.

Comment: Make sure you're are adding two numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force JS to do math instead of putting two strings together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841373/how-to-force-js-to-do-math-instead-of-putting-two-strings-together)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increment a value at localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375433/how-to-increment-a-value-at-localstorage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to parse the "1" in localStorage to an integer using the built in parseInt funtion:

```
var pagenumber = localStorage["pageno"];
var sum = Number.parseInt(pagenumber) + i;
display(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt` to convert your strings to integers in JavaScript:

```
var sum = parseInt(localStorage["pageno"]) + parseInt(i);
display(sum);
```